# Find the probability that a second event occurs after time n given than the first event occurs before time n

Tags: conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

[image: Question]

For the above question, I can solve it quite easily by utilising a counting process however I'm curious as to how one would go solving it by utilising the exponential distribution.

Namely, I'm stuck at understanding how to calculate the probability that the amount of time elapsed since the 2nd customer arrives is greater than 10 minutes given that one customer arrives within 10 minutes i.e. `Pr(V1 + V2 > 10 | V1 <= 10)`

How do we figure out this probability?

Comment: You are actually asked for $\Pr(V_1 + V_2 \le 10)$ which you can calculate using a double integral.  If you wanted the conditional $\Pr(V_1 + V_2 \le 10 \mid V_1  \le 10 )$ then you would divide by a single integral

Answer (score 1):

If $V_1,V_2,\ldots$ are i.i.d. $\mathsf{Expo}(\lambda)$ random variables, it is straightforward to show by induction that $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n V_n$ has Erlang distribution with density
$$
f_n(t) = \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-\lambda t},\ t>0.
$$
It follows then that
$$
\mathbb P(S_n \leqslant T) = \int_0^T \frac{\lambda(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-\lambda t}\ \mathsf dt = 1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\lambda T)^n}{k!} e^{-\lambda T}.\tag 1$$
Here $n=2$, $\lambda = \frac1{10}$, and $T=10$, and so the desired probability is $1-2e^{-1}$.

Alternatively (as Henry suggested), you could compute this probability by a double integral of the joint density of $(V_1,V_2)$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(V_1+V_2\leqslant T) &= \iint_{\{(s,t)\in (0,T)^2 : s<t\}} f_{V_1,V_2}(s,t)\ \mathsf ds\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^T \int_0^{T-t} \lambda e^{-\lambda s}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf ds\ \mathsf dt\\
&= 1-(1+\lambda T)e^{-\lambda T},
\end{align}
which is the same as $(1)$ when $n=2$.